# Redisplaying Dialog in Android WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a webview that some pages request a new dialog window to be displayed.  The problem is that onCreateWindow in the WebChromeClient is only being called the first time the dialog is to be displayed.   The initial call works and creates the necessary window, any time an item is clicked in the web view that would display the new dialog, it is never displayed and onCreateWindow is never called.

The following is the relevant code to create the new dialog:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
    if (isDialog) {
        createDialogWithWebView(view, resultMsg);
        return true;
    }

    return true;
}


protected void createDialogWithWebView(WebView webview, Message resultMsg) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(webview.getContext());
    alert.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    WebView dialogWebView = createNewWebView(webview);
    alert.setView(dialogWebView);
    alert.setNegativeButton("Close", new DismissWebViewAlertDialogOnClickListener(dialogWebView));
    loadWebView(dialogWebView, resultMsg);
    alert.show();
}

protected void loadWebView(WebView view, Message resultMsg) {
    WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
    transport.setWebView(view);
    resultMsg.sendToTarget();
}

private WebView createNewWebView(WebView webView) {
    WebView newWebView = new WebView(webView.getContext());

    setFusionWebViewSettings(newWebView);

    newWebView.setWebChromeClient(this);
    newWebView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient(webView.getContext()));
    newWebView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    return newWebView;
}

protected void setFusionWebViewSettings(WebView newWebView) {
    WebSettings settings = newWebView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
    settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
    settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
}
```

The window is created correctly the first time, anytime after that if the same content is to be created, it never goes to oncreate.  Is there a way to tell the WebView or ChromeClient that the window should be re-created?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this. Buried in the WebChromeClient is an onRequestFocus(Webview view) method that needs to be overridden.   This passes in a view that was previously created.  Note that you if you are going to display the webview in a dialog, you'll need to either cache the previous dialog and reshow it, or remove the webview from the parent, and then create the dialog.

Comment: some code can make things simple to understand @kingargyle